# What is a use case scenario?

Tags: architecture, uml, software-design, use-case, use-case-diagram

So, I'm learning various aspects of design and architecture, such as UML and use cases. But I'm not getting what a use case scenario is and I can't find much about it. Can anyone explain them to me?

Comment: The term "use case scenario" is not defined in the UML specification. Personally, I see "use case scenario" as one possible path to traverse a use case, but I don't have a reference to a source where this is defined as such.

Answer (score 2):

An entire use case can be represented by one activity definition, comprising elements such as decision nodes and activity usages. A scenario is one particular path through such an activity definition. Imagine printing an activity definition and then using a highlighter to trace through decision diamonds. That’s a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario isn't necessarily described as an activity diagram. Very often, the scenarios are first identified and described in plaintext, before being formalized in an activity diagram:

- A very popular format is Alistair Cockburn's template (see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239743872_3_Basic_Use_Case_Template) with some examples).  He suggests to start with a main success scenario, then provide alternative scenarios (for slight variations, extensions, as well as the unhappy case such as errors, exceptions, failures).  By the way, his book "Writing effective use-cases" is a must-read in the field, even if it's more about use-cases than about UML.
- There are many other templates used and sometimes scenarios are called "flow" or "path".  They can be presented in a [tabular form](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/use-cases.html) or in a [chronologicaly numbered sequence](https://www.projectmanagementdocs.com/template/project-documents/use-case-document/#axzz7FhL7KcYd). Sometimes the tabular description has a column for the actor actions and a column for the system action.